# How to get an alarm / warning when it starts to rain

Tags: alarm, weather

How can I be alerted if the weather changes? For example, if it starts raining, I will receive an alarm / warning?  This would obviously be based on some local weather feed, rather than actually detecting rain.

It would be useful because sometimes I have windows open for drying clothes and stuff, and from the room I am normally in one does not notice immediately when it starts raining.   It would be very useful.

Comment: All I could think of is like examining a radar picture, e.g. from http://dwd.de => Deutschlandwetter => Radarbild, but it is always 15 minutes late. So the app must check a bigger area on the picture, then it could warn you in advance.

Comment: According to our [FAQ], this falls into the category *Can you suggest an app that does X?*, which is *expressly off-topic*. A hint, though: [Search the Playstore for "weather-app"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=weather-alarm&c=apps) yields some useful results.

Comment: I've tweaked the question to be more about a problem to be solved rather than an app to be found.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an Android solution, but I think it will work for you.

This [IFTTT Recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/78906) will send an SMS if the weather condition changes to "Rain".

**Trigger** (Weather channel)

- Current condition changes to rain

**Action** (SMS channel)

- Send me an SMS message

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: look at [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), which is basically a scripting app for Android, and set up an alarm based on your weather app or a weather feed.  While not an out of the box solution, I wouldn't think that there would be an app already built that does what you're asking so that's likely you're best bet.